# Adding header to zlib compressed file

Tags: c, zlib

I am trying to use zlib to deflate (compress?) data from a textfile.
It seems to work when I compress a file, but I am trying to prepend
the zlib compressed file with custom header. Both the file and header
should be compressed. However, when I add the header, the length of
the compressed (deflated) file is much shorter than expected and comes
out as an invalid zlib compressed object.

The code works great, until I add the header block of code between the
XXX comments below.

The "FILE *source" variable is a sample file, I typically use
/etc/passwd and the "char *header" is "blob 2172\0".
Without the header block, the output is 904 bytes and deflatable
(decompressable), but with the header it comes out to only 30 bytes.
It also comes out as an invalid zlib object with the header block of
code.

Any ideas where I am making a mistake, specifically why the output is
invalid and shorter *with* the header?

If its relevant, I am writing this on FreeBSD.

```
#define Z_CHUNK16384
#define HEX_DIGEST_LENGTH       257

int
zcompress_and_header(FILE *source, char *header)
{
int ret, flush;
z_stream strm;
unsigned int have;
unsigned char in[Z_CHUNK];
unsigned char out[Z_CHUNK];

FILE *dest = stdout; // This is a temporary test

strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
ret = deflateInit(&strm, Z_BEST_SPEED);
//ret = deflateInit2(&strm, Z_BEST_SPEED, Z_DEFLATED, 15 | 16, 8,
Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);

if (ret != Z_OK)
     return ret;

/* XXX Beginning of writing the header */

strm.next_in = (unsigned char *) header;
strm.avail_in = strlen(header) + 1;

do {
     strm.avail_out = Z_CHUNK;
     strm.next_out = out;
     if (deflate (& strm, Z_FINISH) < 0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "returned a bad status of.\n");
          exit(0);
     }
     have = Z_CHUNK - strm.avail_out;
     fwrite(out, 1, have, stdout);
} while(strm.avail_out == 0);

/* XXX End of writing the header */

do {
     strm.avail_in = fread(in, 1, Z_CHUNK, source);
     if (ferror(source)) {
          (void)deflateEnd(&strm);
          return Z_ERRNO;
     }

     flush = feof(source) ? Z_FINISH : Z_NO_FLUSH;
     strm.next_in = in;

     do {
          strm.avail_out = Z_CHUNK;
          strm.next_out = out;
          ret = deflate(&strm, flush);
          have = Z_CHUNK - strm.avail_out;
          if (fwrite(out, 1, have, dest) != have || ferror(dest)) {
               (void)deflateEnd(&strm);
               return Z_ERRNO;
          }
     } while(strm.avail_out == 0);

} while (flush != Z_FINISH);

} // End of function
```

Comment: Some questions, for clarification: 1) you defined "#define Z_CHUNK16384", I suppese it should be "#define Z_CHUNK 16384". If Z_CHUNK is defined elsewhere, the program compiles but uses an unexpectec chunk size.

Comment: 2) You are using strlen on header. Is the header a null terminated string?

Comment: Z_CHUNK is called CHUNK and is defined as 16384 in the zpipe.c example from the zlib documentation. Just from knowing the code, I know that header is not null, but I take your point of needing to add an error checking.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to point out that there should be a space between "Z_CHUNK" and "16384" in your #define at line 1, otherwise you don't actually define the macro "Z_CHUNK", but "Z_CHUNK13384".

Answer (score 1):

`deflate` is not an archiver. It only compresses a stream. Once the stream is exhausted, your options are very limited. The manual clearly says that

> If the parameter flush is set to Z_FINISH, pending input is processed, pending output is flushed and deflate returns with Z_STREAM_END if there was enough output space. If deflate returns with Z_OK or Z_BUF_ERROR, this function **must** be called again with Z_FINISH and more output space (updated avail_out) but no more input data, until it returns with Z_STREAM_END or an error. After deflate has returned Z_STREAM_END, **the only possible operations** on the stream are deflateReset or deflateEnd.

However, you are calling `deflate` for the file after you `Z_FINISH` the header, and `zlib` behaves unpredictably. The likely fix is to not use `Z_FINISH` for the header at all, and let the other side understand that the first line in the decompressed string is a header (or impose some archiving protocol understood by both sides).

Comment: Thanks for your excellent comment. I read the manual page and your comment - so do not use Z_FINISH in the header. Of the remaining options (Z_NO_FLUSH, Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH, Z_SYNC_FLUSH, Z_FULL_FLUSH, Z_BLOCK and Z_TREES) what should I use?

Comment: @FarhanYusufzai From the zlib manual: "_Normally the parameter flush is set to Z_NO_FLUSH, which allows deflate to decide how much data to accumulate before producing output, in order to maximize compression._"

Answer (score 1):

Your first calls of `deflate()` should use `Z_NO_FLUSH`, not `Z_FINISH`. `Z_FINISH` should only be used when the last of the data to be compressed is provided with the `deflate()` call.